# C# filling a dataset from the database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dataset

I have some troubles with dataset in c#. I want to fill it with content from the database, but can't get it to work.

Here is my code:

from the main database layer containing the connection string

```
public static SqlCommand GetDbCommand(string sql)
        {
            if (dbconn.State.ToString().CompareTo("Open") != 0)
                Open();
            if (dbCmd == null)
            {
                dbCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, dbconn);
            }
            dbCmd.CommandText = sql;
            return dbCmd;
        }
```

This is the method that should fill the dataset from my DBMovie class

```
public static DataSet GetMovieSet()
    {
        DataSet movieSet = new DataSet();

        string sql = "select * from Movie";
        dbCmd = DBConnection.GetDbCommand(sql);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        da.Fill(movieSet);

        DBConnection.Close();
        return movieSet;

    }
```

How do I connect the dataAdapter together with the database connection?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but read about the `using` keyword and use it. If an exception is thrown in your code, you leak valuable resources such as DB connections.

Comment: `new SqlDataAdapter(dbCmd);`  I would chuck those global variables, they just make your life harder when debugging code later.

Comment: What do you mean you "can't get it to work"? Do you get an exception? Does it just give you an empty dataset?

Comment: LarsTech has your answer and great advice. Eric J also has great advice. Take their advice, because your current approach has you headed for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the adapter to the command like so:

```
    dbCmd = DBConnection.GetDbCommand(sql);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = dbCmd; //Add this
    da.Fill(movieSet);
```